# fopen can create a file but cannot reopen file in C

Tags: c, fopen

I am unable to open a file I just created using `fopen()`, I tried this code on both Linux and Windows. I also tried this code using complete path.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

    char c;
    FILE *myFile = fopen("name.txt", "w"); //file name.txt created
    fprintf(myFile, "My name is %s", "Adam"); //text saved
    fclose(myFile); //file closed

    FILE *myOpenFile;
    if(myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r") == NULL);
    {
        printf("No such file\n"); //no such file is executed
        return 0;
    }

    while (c=!EOF)
    {
        c = fgetc(myOpenFile);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(myOpenFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And another question showing why putting the assignment in the `if` clause is a **bad** idea.  What's wrong with two lines of `myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r"); if (myOpenFile == NULL )...`?  What did you gain by stuffing all that into one line?  Well, other than non-working code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Alternatively, removing the comparison would fix the condition: `if (myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r"))` is fine.

Comment: You let a `;` after the `if (...) `, so the bloc after is always executed

Answer (score 4):

```
myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r") == NULL
```

would be

```
(myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r")) == NULL
```

Otherwise you were assigning to `myOpenFile` the result of `==` which is `0` or `1`. Remember `==` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `=`. So it does the comparison before assigning it to `myOpenFile`.

Another major thing which might seem minor to you is - return value of `fgetc` is `int` not `char`. So `int c` will be correct usage over here - not `char c`.

Your `c` was uninitialized - initialize with some value and then do the comparison. And as suggested it will be (melpomene)

```
while ((c = fgetc(myOpenFile))!=EOF)
{
     printf("%c", c);
}
```

Earlier you basically negated the value `-1` (EOF) and it is `0` and that `0` value is assigned to `c` and the result of assignment expression  is the value assigned which is `0` and that `0` being considered false - the loop is never entered.

Also notice that earlier you printed the value of `c` when `EOF` is assigned to it. That is not what your intention is. The corrected code should be something like as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a typo in

```
if(myOpenFile = fopen("name.txt", "r") == NULL);
    {
        printf("No such file\n"); //no such file is executed
        return 0;
    }
```

The `;` at the end of the first line makes a code block that does nothing.
Then the following code block is always executed.

Aside: you are using the wrong variable type.

```
char c;
```

should be

```
int c;
```

as the man page will tell you. Don't worry about

```
printf("%c", c);
```

because was `char` is promoted to `int` anyway.